# Fancytree how to select/deselect all clone node

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am use fancybox plug in, and don't know how to select/deselect all clone node?
I am set refkey but not working. Do you have any ideas. Thanks a lot.

```
$("#tree1111").fancytree({
                checkbox: true,
                extensions: ["clones"],
                source: SOURCE,
                clones: {
                    highlightClones: true
                },

                select: function(e, data){
                    var clones = data.node.getCloneList();
                    if( clones ) {
                        alert("Clones: "+ $.map(clones, function(n){ return "" + n;}).join(", "));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#tree1111").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    extensions: ["clones"],
    source: SOURCE,
    clones: {
        highlightClones: true
    },
    click: function (event, data) {
        var clones = data.node.getCloneList();

        if(clones){
            $.each(clones, function (key, value) {
                if (value.isSelected() == false) {
                    value.setSelected();
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    value.setSelected(false);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```