# How to trigger unselect/deselec event on fancytree

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, fancytree

I search through Fancytree events. I found `select`, `activate`, `beforeSelect` and some. but I cannot see `unselect`/`deselect` event. Maybe I did not search properly?

How can I trigger function on this event?

Comment: You can maybe deselect them with `.setSelected(false);` might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254287/fancytree-how-to-select-deselect-all-clone-node

Comment: Yes, I know. but how can execute function when item is unselected?

Comment: if you are using [this fancytree](https://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/index.html)  the events you are looking for are described [here](https://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeEvents)